# Weird (?): Use Cauchy's Integral formula to calculate $\int _{|z|=3} \frac{z}{z^2-\pi^2}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Weird (?): Use Cauchy's Integral formula to calculate $\large \int _{|z|=3} \frac{z}{z^2-\pi^2}dz$.

But the function $\frac{z}{z^2-\pi^2}$ is holomorphic on all of $|z|=3$. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Look closely at Cauchy's Integral Formula. Why do you think there is a problem here?

Comment: Oh... So I can just calculate for instance for $\frac {z}{z+pi}$ divided by $z-\pi$ (dunno how to make triple fraction) and it will be just ok...